# I hava make a script mod to make remote computers work, but some computer work different

Tags: ansible

when I run ansible playbook script mod use shell script, I don't want to get answer "\r\n" in  stdout_lines first element.

some computer return \r\n in first

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test
  tasks: 
    - script: echoTest.sh
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out

most are the expected answer:
    "out": {
        "changed": true, 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.184.141 closed.\r\n", 
        "stderr_lines": [
            "Shared connection to 192.168.184.141 closed."
        ], 
        "stdout": "Hi\r\n", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Hi"
        ]
    }
```

but some are the unexpected answer:

```
    "out": {
        "changed": true, 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.184.141 closed.\r\n", 
        "stderr_lines": [
            "Shared connection to 192.168.184.141 closed."
        ], 
        "stdout": "\r\nHi\r\n", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "", 
            "Hi"
        ]
    }
```

I don't want the element "" in stdout_lines, How can I work out it?

Comment: in your echoTest.sh script, is your !#/bin/bash on the first line?  In the example you have posted it appears that you have a newline above it?

Comment: yes, it is. #!/bin/bash is on the first line. Most important of all, the most remote computer is the right answer.

Comment: Is should not happen, but try to put string in single quote " ' " or check if any unwanted hidden(special char) in the string or delete & add the same line without copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real playbook is:

---

```
- hosts: test
  become_user: root
  become: yes
  tasks: 
    - script: echoTest.sh
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```

if I use `become: yes`  out of tasks, some computer will get the error answer,
buf if I use `become: yes` in tasks, it all be ok, like follow:

---

```
- hosts: test
  become_user: root
  tasks: 
    - become: yes
      script: echoTest.sh
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```

oh, I'm not sure is it a bug, I can't find other better way to solve it.

Comment: do not use ansible_become_pass to control the remote computer,  maybe ansible analysis `\r\n` after `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

To help debugging I would suggest checking "some computer" "echo" command, for example,
logging on and running "echo" manually (checking "which echo" and "alias echo") and/or hardcode which echo to run in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hi"
```